# Gradle: Groovy build source code directory

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have created a groovy `class` in the `build.gradle` file to customize the build.

```
    buildscript {
       repositories {
          mavenLocal()
          mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
         // dependencies here.
       }
    }

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory

    class YamlToJsonFilter extends FilterReader {

    // my class definition here.
    .....
    ...
    }
task yamlToJson(type: Copy) {
   from 'src/main/yaml'
   into 'build/jsonschema'
   filter(YamlToJsonFilter)
   rename('(.*).yml', '$1.json')
}
```

Having groovy class in build file doesn't look great. I want to move this class to independent file and use it here. I don't know the directory where this class should live and how to use its reference in the build.gradle file.

**Edit1** As Jeff Scott Brown suggested in the comment section, I created `buildSrc` directory under project root directory and created Jeff `YamlToJsonFilter.groovy` file in the new directory. Here is the directory structure

```
├── build.gradle
├── buildSrc
│   ├── YamlToJsonFilter.groovy
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── libs
│   │   │   └── buildSrc.jar
│   │   └── tmp
│   │       └── jar
│   │           └── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── build.gradle
```

I get this error:

```
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/rakesh.kumar/ll/reference-project/event_schema/build.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'sfl2_event_schema'.
> Could not get unknown property 'YamlToJsonFilter' for task ':yamlToJson' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Build script is not able to recognize `YamlToJsonFilter` and complaining about it. I also notice that all the tasks related with `buildSrc` are always showing `UP-TO-DATE` that makes me feel that it doesn't even detect `YamlToJsonFilter.groovy` file.

**Edit2**
I created the `main/src/groovy/` under `buildSrc` directory and moved the file under groovy directory. Now it is able to compile the task and I can refer the class from the build.gradle file.

Comment: You probably want the `buildSrc` directory.  See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for providing the answer. I created `buildSrc` directory in project root directory and created YamlToJsonFilter.groovy file under this new directory. But some how it is not picking the class file. Do I need to have an import statement in `build.gradle`

Comment: @Rakesh: looks like you found an answer to your question. May I suggest you post a direct answer with your findings? :-)